# Using image from same folder as compiled Jar not working

Tags: java, swing

All I am trying to do is create a JLabel using an image located in the same directory as the .jar and if it does not exist it will load a default photo located inside the .jar iteself. The picture exists in the folder however it always defaults to the picture inside the .jar

```
String path = this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();

File logo = new File(path + "logo.png");

JLabel lblNewLabel_1;
if (logo.exists()){
    lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(logo.getPath()));
} else {
    lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource("/com/daniel/Coffee.png")));    
}

frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel_1, BorderLayout.WEST);

final JLabel lblStatus = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource("/com/daniel/status1.png")));
frame.getContentPane().add(lblStatus, BorderLayout.EAST);
```

Comment: Check for getResource returning null.

Comment: You should not use `String path = this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();`. To get the external file you should use the Path class: `Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("logo.png");`

Comment: If `getResource` returns null we will get `NPE` here i think, don't we?

Comment: What's wrong with `new File("logo.png")`?  Assuming that the execution context is the same directory as the jar...

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way to diagnose this issue is to apply simple `System.out.println()` like here

```
String path = this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath(;
System.our.println("Jar path is "+path); <- you will see the actual path content here
File logo = new File(path + "logo.png");
```

Check the result and adjust concatenate path as needed. I guess that path is either pointing to different directory than you think it is, or it is simply missing a `File.separator` at the end. Try out and share the results!

Comment: I did this and likewise the path is being '...\logo.jar' And the actual image itself is just being '\logo.jar\logo.png' How do i go up a directory in that String path?

Comment: If `getLocation()` returns `File` then `getParentFile()`. You can always use `/../` to go one level up.

Comment: You really should not concatenate the file name yourself but rely upon API methods.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing a '/' at the end of `path`. Do it this way:

```
String path = this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
File logo = new File(new File(path).getParentFile(), "logo.png");
...
```

The catch is to first creating a File for the containing directory and then using the constructor `File(File dir, String name)` instead of string concatenation.

Furthermore, you should check folder and file permissions in advance, providing proper logging output for error diagnosis. For this, use `canRead()` instead of `exists()` (assuming `log` is available as some logging facility - replace with the logging mechanism of your choice):

```
String path = this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
File sourceLocation = new File(path);

// go up in the hierarchy until there is a directory
while (sourceLocation != null && !sourceLocation.isDirectory()) {
    sourceLocation = sourceLocation.getParentFile();
    if (sourceLocation == null) {
        log.warn(path + " is not a directory but has no parent");
    }
}

if (sourceLocation != null && sourceLocation.canRead()) {
    File logo = new File(sourceLocation, "logo.png");
    if (logo.canRead()) {
        log.info("Using logo " + logo.getAbsolutePath());
        lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(logo.getPath()));
    } else {
        log.warn("can not read " + logo.getAbsolutePath());
    }
}

if (lblNewLabel_1 == null) {
    log.warn("logo location not accessible, using default logo: " + sourceLocation);
    lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(Main.class.getResource("/com/daniel/Coffee.png")));
}

// ...
```

Comment: Looking at where the file path of logo is it appears its doing ...\logo.jar\logo.png

Comment: Okay, I added a call to `getParentFile()` to remove the `logo.jar` from the path.